# What does $1^Tt$ mean?

Tags: notation, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I've been given the following $\ell_1$ norm approximation problem

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & 1^{T} t\\ \text{subject to} & -t\leq Ax-b \leq t\end{array}$$

What does $1^T t$ mean?

Comment: $1$ is likely referring to the column vector of all ones with the same dimensions as $t$. Therefore, $1^Tt$ is the sum of all the entries of $t$.

Comment: This is a ([tag:linear-programming]) problem.